AlpineJS render x-data from Eloquent Object
I would like to handle parameter from eloquent object
Livewire component
$this->marketplaces = Marketplace::with('website')->whereNotIn('id',$existsId)->limit(200)->get()->keyBy('id');

Livewire blade
<div class="p-2" x-data="{marketplaces:@json($marketplaces)}">
    <span x-text="marketplaces"></span>
</div>

I did this one and receiving an error response

livewire.js?id=8a199ab2:980 Alpine Expression Error: Unexpected token
';'
Expression: "{marketplaces:{"

Am I missing something?

After trying many times, I thought this is the working one
<div class="p-2" x-data="() => {
    return{
        marketplaces: {{$marketplaces}},
    }
}">
    <span x-text="marketplaces"></span>
</div>

Hopefully, this can help other who is new in alpineJS. I saw many tutorials that is using @json while I tried it and its not working. I have no idea why, I am just thinking that livewire seems to convert it automatically into json. So, we do not need to use @json. CMIIW
